# Best way to compare two tables in SQL by matching string?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a program where the goal is to take data from an API, and capture the differences in data from minute to minute.  It involves three tables: Table 1 (for new data), Table 2 (for previous minutes data), Results table (for the results).

The sequence of the program is like this:
Update table 1 -> Calculate the differences from table 2 and update a "Results" table with the differences -> Copy table 1 to table 2.

Then it repeats!  It's simple and it works.

Here is my SQL query:

```
Insert into Results (symbol, bid, ask, description, Vol_Dif, Price_Dif, Time) Select * FROM(
        Select symbol, bid, ask, description, Vol_Dif, Price_Dif, '$now' as Time FROM ( 
        Select t1.symbol, t1.bid, t1.ask, t1.description, (t1.volume - t2.volume) AS Vol_Dif, (t1.totalPrice - t2.totalPrice) AS Price_Dif
        FROM `Table_1` t1 
        Inner Join (
        Select id, volume, ask, totalPrice FROM Table_2) t2 
        ON t2.id = t1.id) as test
```

The tables are identical in structure, obviously.  The primary key is the 'id' field that auto-increments.  And as you can see, I am comparing both tables on the basis of these 'id' fields being equal.

The PROBLEM is that the API seems to be inconsistent.  One API call will have 50,000 entries.  The next one will have 51,000 entries.  And the entries are not just added to the end or added to the beginning, they are mixed into the middle.

So, comparing on equal ID's means I am comparing entries for DIFFERENT data, IF the API calls return a different number entries.

The data that I am trying to get the differences of is the 'bid', 'ask', 'Vol_Dif', 'Price_Dif' from minute to minute.  There are many instances of the same 'symbol's, so I couldn't compare with this.  The ONLY other way to compare entries from table to table, beside the matching ID's, would be matching the "description" fields.

I have tried this.  The script is almost the same as above except the end of the query is

```
ON t2.description = t1.description
```

The problem is that looking for matching description fields takes 3 minutes for 50,000 entries, whereas looking for matching ID's takes 1 second.

Is there a better, faster way to do what I'm trying to do?  Thanks in advance.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there an index on `description`?

Comment: The ways to do this are going to be product specific. Please edit your question and add a tag for the specific RDBMS that you're using. [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: The RDBMS is mariaDB, sorry.  @Eric Brandt

Comment: Is there _one_ set of diffs?  Or is there a set of diffs for every minute in the past?